# Easy way to remove formatting (e.g. linebreaks)

Tags: formatting

I have defined the following shortcut for some text

```
\newcommand{\sometext}{text\\text\\text}
```

Now I would like to use this in some other place but with the linebreaks removed. So is there an easy way to do it (e.g. something like `"\remove_linebreaks{\sometext}"`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will change `\\` into a space:

```
\newcommand{\removelinebreaks}[1]{%
  \begingroup\def\\{ }#1\endgroup}

\removelinebreaks{\sometext}
```

Comment: `\\ ` has an optional star and an optional argument. Something like `\def\\{\@ifstar {\@gobbleopt}{\@gobbleopt}}\providecommand*\@gobbleopt[1][]{}` would handle these too.

Comment: @Schweinebacke
How is this chunk supposed to work?  Compilation fails like this:

`! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`
`See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.`
`Type  H <return>  for immediate help.`
` ...`
`l.65 ...bbleopt}{\@gobbleopt}}\providecommand*\@go`
`bbleopt[1][]{}`
`?`

Comment: @Frotz:  Use it instead of `\def\\{ }` in egreg's code, but → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do or ask a new question.