# Use the value of \@title with removed linebreak

Tags: formatting, titles

Related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page), except taking it a step further, I'm wondering if there's a way to use `\@title` with a line break removed. For example,
`\title{Hello\\world}` I would like to become `Helloworld` or `Hello world` when I access the title later in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi, just found an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35884/easy-way-to-remove-formatting-e-g-linebreaks) for how to remove a linebreak from a string. So I'll be using the `titling` package to give access to `\thetitle` element, to get an italic linebreak-free title via

```
\begingroup\def\\{}\emph{\thetitle}\endgroup
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more simple to use  an additional `\newcommand{\myTitle}{HelloWombat}` instead of dealing with groups and redefining a linebreak with an unaware definition hammer?

Comment: @Johannes_B You mean just retyping the title into a new command? Sure, that's simpler, but if I change my title then I'd have to change it in two places. Plus if I share my code and someone changes the title for their situation, then this will work for them without them having to understand and read through all of the code.

Comment: I guess that `\begingroup \let\\=\space \emph{\thetitle}\endgroup` would be better, wouldn’t it?